# Tomato Mosaic Virus

Tags: diseases, tomatoes

My tomato plants apparently had the tomato mosaic virus this year - and probably last year as well. This is according to my neighbor, who I asked because I've been asking everyone if they know what the problem is. I normally have great success with tomato plants, but not this year. And to some extent, not last year. So here's my question. If the problem has carried over the winter to this year from last year, I'll have it in my tomato plants next year, too. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: I don't suppose you have any photos of the problem? Where were they growing, greenhouse or outdoors? What were they growing in if in pots, new potting soil or garden soil? Do you smoke or could the plants have been exposed to tobacco smoke? What were the symptoms the plants displayed?

Comment: They are outside, along a fence, in the ground. No one in my family smokes. I can't get photos because it's too late in the season. Thank you for pointing out what would be helpful to know. I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tobacco mosaic virus is hard to eradicate. The best thing you can do after removing all weeds and affected plants is to replace the soil for about 2 shovels deep were the tomatoes and other affected plants have been with new soil, preferably organic. You also need to check the vicinity for other plants with the same symptoms, since mosaic viruses cross-contaminate other species. Permaculture tends to help in growing plants that outgrow or are more resistant to mosaic virus, regular weeding also helps in preventing it. I have a patch myself that I need to replace because it has already spread to susceptible plants in the vicinity that are in poor soil, but since we grow entirely organic in the larger patch that is next to it, there's nothing in that part of the garden affected, while it is just next to it, with susceptible plant genus in there as well (the affected patch is still soil from the previous owners we left in there without doing anything about it for 2 years aside from planting some herbs in it and not weeding much honestly).

Comment: My adjacent oregano and catnip patches, normally very hard plants, seem to have become ill, too. Browning and dying back without explanation. My thumb is very green so I've been horrified. They're like my babies, almost. I appreciate knowing this disease spreads. I guess I've got a lot of work to do.